# SSIS DATA FLOW (2 packages into a single package)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I have created 2 different packages where in package 1 we are loading data from two different tables (current and history tables) and in the second package we are loading only from current table to destination table.

Task: I want to use only one package instead of two packages  where when it runs first time it should load data from both current and history table and when we run it for second time it should only load data from current table to destination.

Can this be done in a single data flow? If so could you explain me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like some kind of modified incremental load. Anyway there are many techniques:

Create 2 parallel DFT,1 with current source and another with history source. An `execute sql task` will trigger it based on below 2 methods:

**note:** Handle parallel processing wisely, else sources will conflict.

[image: img]

1. Maintain 'DataLoad_ID'

   - Here you will maintain a separate table with count of number of loads. A `execute sql task` will read this. When DataLoad < 1, then enable history source DFT via `constraints`. Else run only current source DFT.
2. Via existing logic.

   - Using `Execute SQL Task`, check if your data warehouse is populated(use any logic, for instance, check for default columns: Created_Dttm, Updated_Dttm). If not, then enable history source DFT via `constraints`. Else run only current source DFT.